# Why using SEEK_END doesn't work here?

Tags: c, file-io, seek, lseek

So I'm trying to learn C file IO operations from a snippet from the university. My problem is that `SEEK_END` doesn't work as I expect it to work.

Let met give you more details:

input.txt:

```
abcd-abcd-abcd
```

code:

```
int fd, fdr, l1, l2, wb1, wb2;
char buf[25];

fd = open("input.txt", O_WRONLY);
fdr = open("input.txt", O_RDONLY);

l1 = lseek(fd, -3, SEEK_END);
wb1 = write(fd, "xy", 2);

l2 = lseek(fd, 4, SEEK_SET);
write(fd, "12", 2);

lseek(fdr, 0, SEEK_SET);
wb2 = read(fdr, buf, 20);
write(1, buf, wb2);
```

My problem is writing "xy". I expect the output to be

```
abcd12bcd-axyd
```

Instead it is

```
abcd12bcd-abcd
```

Why the "xy" is not written?

Comment: Works here (gcc (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5) as expected, writing out `abcd12bcd-axyd` to the console.

Comment: If look the file size of `input.txt` (using the shell or any file browser) what do you get before and after you ran the program? `14`?

Comment: On which platform/OS do you experience this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Close the write only file (or sync data to disk) before reading the file from another handle.

In your case, data is written to file, but not synced to disk yet. So when 2nd handle tries to read the data, it gets old stale data.

```
int fd, fdr, l1, l2, wb1, wb2;
char buf[25];

fd = open("input.txt", O_WRONLY);
fdr = open("input.txt", O_RDONLY);

l1 = lseek(fd, -3, SEEK_END);
wb1 = write(fd, "xy", 2);

l2 = lseek(fd, 4, SEEK_SET);
write(fd, "12", 2);

close(fd); 

lseek(fdr, 0, SEEK_SET);
wb2 = read(fdr, buf, 20);
write(1, buf, wb2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to sync data to the disk before reading it again. Because data is not written at the time of your read. you need to close file before read.